# Switching between python versions using virtualenvwrapper on Mac OS

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, virtualenv, virtualenvwrapper

I am trying to figure out how to switch between different Python versions on my Mac using virtualenvwrapper package.

My Mac came with Python2.7 and I've installed the latest version (Python3.7). I have figured out how to make an environment with Python3.7 using the following:

```
mkvirtualenv -p /usr/local/bin/python3 p3
```

But when I check PYTHONPATH, VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_PYTHON, and VIRTUALENV_PYTHON, they all point to the original Python 2.7.

How do I know that the environment I created is actually running Python3?

I am new to virtual environments and the Mac world, so this has all be a bit confusing to figure out. I appreciate any input.

Comment: When you run `python --version` what do you get?

Comment: just install anaconda for mac, it's much easier

Comment: opening a python shell with just `python` should do the trick as well as it prints the version. Don't forget to `deactivate` and `workon` the different environments i.e be sure to switch between the environments.

Comment: @ArdentLearner You're right. Thank you!

Comment: @tmcnicol I got Python3.7, which is exactly what i wanted. 

Why is it that PYTHONPATH, for example, doesn't reflect the same version as the environment? Do environmental variables not change under different environments?

Comment: Virtual env wrapper is written on top of virtual env, I know it is shocking :), as far as I can tell virtual env does not manipulate your python path. One of the advantages of this is that it allows the system python to work as normal. If you run `which python`, you will see the path of the python that you are using, unfortunately I have a different setup, using pyenv + virtual env wrapper, so I will struggle to replicate your situation exactly but for me it runs a shim which determines which version of python to use when I execute a python program and does not touch my path at all.

Answer (score 1):

Do this:

```
python3.6 -m virtualenv /path/to/your/venv
```

This will guarantee your virtualenv to install for *that* specific python version.

If you are not sure where your python executable is, fire up a python console:

```
>>> import sys
>>> print(sys.executable)
/full/path/to/your/python/executable
```

You'll usually find other python versions lying there - usually they're symlinked to your `/usr/local/bin/` which will make you able to call them by name , e.g. `python3.6`